# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - but I can see that the value does exist

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using the codeigniter4 framework.  I have a database called taskapp.  The db has 2 tables as follows;

```
table: user
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| email    | varchar(60) | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and this is my other table

```
table: post
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| post_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_user_id | int(11) | NO   |     |         |                |
| post     | varchar(60) | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When I update the post table (eg change post), I get the following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`taskapp`.`post`, 
CONSTRAINT `post_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`post_user_id`)
REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I checked table and field collation and both are the same.

I understand from reading other posts that essentially I am trying to update post table that doesn't have corresponding reference in user table.  The post_user_id is 58 and in the user table I see 58.

For now, I am working on update of text ('post').  Next I want to change the post_user_id to another id in the user table.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: You can run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` to get more detailed information on why the FK failure occurred.

Comment: I also suggest checking to see if there are any triggers on the post table that change the `NEW.post_user_id`.

Comment: I have looked at the post table and the user table and found zero triggers mentioned.  I will look into how to use SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G.  Thank you.

Comment: @BillKarwin btw, I seem to have a relationship from post to user.  I can see this by viewing relationship when in the post table.  When I am in the user table, I cannot see such relationship.  Is this a potential?

Comment: A foreign key typically goes one way. It is normal for the constraint to exist in one table and not the other. E.g. a row in `post` must reference an existing user, but a row can exist in `user` without being referenced by any post. So there is no constraint needed in `user`.

Comment: ok, SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G helped a lot.  Thanks.  I can see that the query is being made as an INSERT, rather than an update.  I can further see that post_user_id is not being included.  Thanks.  Will work on this and let you know how it works out.  Nice new command learnt.

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you again for your help.  Indeed, was a couple of problems, all of which 
 'SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G' helped isolate the problem.  Firstly, as stated, it was trying to insert rather than update.  I use ->save which automatically selects whether it is an update by determining whether the primary key, or in this case, post_id, is present.  If it is present, it is an update.  If not, insert.  So, including post_is into ->save() fixed both problems.  Thank you!